# Android Message Queue RabbitMQ vs. ZeroMQ for RPC style actions?

Tags: android, rest, rabbitmq, zeromq, rpc

I am trying to figure out which is the best solution for a mobile android device for sending "rpc" style calls. These are basically database queries that will return information that i will serialize into java objects. Because this will be over the WAN i need something with some type of security (SSL/TLS should be fine..) but i am still not 100% sure which approach to take.

1. ZeroMQ
   Basically take this, use the ZMQCurve security library and build an RPC style system from scratch?
2. RabbitMQ AMPQ
   Do this with some type of SSL wrapper and have RPCStyle with the reply-to header field set?
3. RabbitmQ STOMP

Do this with some type of wss and RPC style semantics over the websocket.

The main thing i am looking for is

1. something that can handle a lot of requests, can be distributed.
2. Something that is not going to kill the battery on the mobile device.

I think the most important feature i am looking for is some way for the device to complete a SSL handshake 1 time with the message broker (or zeromq load balancer) and have a socket open... but no keepalive. This way I can always send requests from the device to the server, wait for my response (async) and then once the response is completed do not send keep alives or use the battery in any draining way. But, i do not want to have to do a handshake everytime i send a message.

What paradigm would sound best? What system? Is a REST approach possibly the best?

Comment: today's answer would probably be grpc or an amqp like rabbit mq. zmq if you wanted a brokerless amqp i guess.